# Article got major revision from a high impact factor journal, chances of acceptance

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper to a very high impact factor journal in my field: quantum technologies. I received an email saying that the article needed major revision. The reviewers' comments are pretty reasonable and I have now incorporated all of them into the manuscript. The reviewer also wrote that they liked some sections of the manuscripts. Both the reviewers raised comments but both also said the manuscript was good and in demand. However, the revision I have done is over 4 pages and my original manuscripts was 24 pages. Based on your experience, what are the chances of acceptance?

Comment: Why do you care? You have the option to improve your paper. Use it. Other than that, I do not see what you gain by estimating quotas, unless you want to open a betting office.

Comment: My experience shows that the chances of acceptance are pretty high. Sexagenarian, I recall only one case in my entire career when a major revision did not satisfy the reviewers, and my paper was rejected. Based on my personal statistics (which is, of course, individual), I would evaluate the chances for acceptance as 90 - 95 %, provided you properly follow the reviewers' requirements.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Are you seriously asking why an academic would be interested in the probability of their paper being accepted? You're being dishonest and cruel.

Comment: @user479223 "You're being dishonest and cruel". Let's assume I am. However, how do you extract this information from my comment? My flippancy was intended to pull OP into a different perspective: the OP's focus should be on improving the paper to the editor's liking, rather than on futile considerations. It's the same  as when doing a very difficult balancing act, to stay in the "flow". Once worrying about falling down, one falls. Maybe it's honest to tell the acrobat to look down and see how far they are from the ground. I personally prefer them not to fall. But maybe you see that as cruel.

Answer (score 3):

The chance is better than before you received this major revision. Other than that we cannot say much.

Comment: It is way better than a desk reject…